# Error 500 in Magento 1.9.3 products admin page

Tags: magento-1.9, http-error-500, form-key

I tried to upgrade magento in order to solve login problem But after I revert back I can't access Products page in Admin. Looking errors I receive

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
> Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController::_setForcedFormKeyActions()
> in
> /home/username/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
> on line 55

I looked at line 55 but there are comments and no code.

any help please?

Comment: Have you tried removing cache directory?

Comment: Yes every move I do I empty cache first

Comment: Can you share initial code of your file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php `

Comment: https://www.filefactory.com/file/2a24f0a5sw49/ProductController.php

Comment: Strange.. if you have IDE like phpstorm, I would suggest you search `_setForcedFormKeyActions` function in your whole code and check from where it is calling

Comment: Do you have fpm on your server? if yes, please flush fpm cache from one of these commands `service php7.2-fpm restart` or `service php7.1-fpm restart`... FPM actually create cache of php files, this could be the reason

Comment: After your tip about fpm I found out that I havent restarted nginx. And the products working. But I receive another error in the Checkout when the order is submitted.

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getIsMultiShipping() on null in /home/epiplaagapi/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php on line 63**

Comment: That's great.. The error you are showing is related to sessions, try flushing session, if it is in database, then truncate sessions table, or if it is in files, then delete sessions directory, then try again